# How can I do to find which constraints identify the optimal vertex and which ones do not?

Tags: java, constraints, gurobi, vertex

I have found the optimal and all the values ​​of the variables, how can I do to find the constraints that make me the optimal vertex? Is there a method or something like that?
These are my constraints:

w >= xir pir - xin pin

```
    GRBLinExpr expr = new GRBLinExpr();
    for(int i=0; i<M; i++) {
        for(int r=0; r<K/2; r++) {
            expr.addTerm(pij[i][r], xij[i][r]);
        }
        for(int n=K/2; n<K; n++) {
            expr.addTerm(-pij[i][n], xij[i][n]);
        }
    }
    model.addConstr(w, GRB.GREATER_EQUAL, expr, "vincolo " + count);
    count++;
```

w >= xin pin - xir pir

```
    expr = new GRBLinExpr();
    for(int i=0; i<M; i++) {
        for(int n=K/2; n<K; n++) {
            expr.addTerm(pij[i][n], xij[i][n]);
        }
        for(int r=0; r<K/2; r++) {
            expr.addTerm(-pij[i][r], xij[i][r]);
        }
    }
    model.addConstr(w, GRB.GREATER_EQUAL, expr, "vincolo " + count);
    count++;
```

xij <= tij

```
    expr = new GRBLinExpr();
    for(int i=0; i<M; i++) {
        for(int j=0; j<K; j++) {
            expr.addTerm(1, xij[i][j]);
            model.addConstr(expr, GRB.LESS_EQUAL, tij[i][j], "vincolo " + count);
            count++;
        }
    }
```

xij cij <= bi

```
    expr = new GRBLinExpr();
    for(int i=0; i<M; i++) {
        for(int j=0; j<K; j++) {
            expr.addTerm(cij[i][j], xij[i][j]);
        }
        model.addConstr(expr, GRB.LESS_EQUAL, bi[i], "vincolo " + count);
        count++;
    }
```

xij cij >= omega*bi

```
    expr = new GRBLinExpr();
    int budget = 0;
    double valore = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<M; i++) {
        budget += bi[i];
    }
    valore = budget*omega;
    for(int j=0; j<K; j++) {
        for(int i=0; i<M;i++) {
            expr.addTerm(cij[i][j], xij[i][j]);
        }
        model.addConstr(expr, GRB.GREATER_EQUAL, valore, "vincolo " + count); 
        count++;
    }
```

xij pij >= s

```
    expr = new GRBLinExpr();
    for(int i=0; i<M; i++) {
        for(int j=0; j<K; j++) {
            expr.addTerm(pij[i][j], xij[i][j]);
        }
    }
    model.addConstr(expr, GRB.GREATER_EQUAL, s, "vincolo" + count);
```

Comment: Maybe add your code? How are people supposed to answer like this?

Comment: Sorry but I'm new, now i have edited

Answer (score 1):

You need to look at the [constraint attributes](https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/9.5/refman/linear_constraint_attribut.html). To do this, you should save references to the GRBConstr objects when you call GRBModel.addConstr().